# Celery run worker with -Ofair from python

Tags: python, concurrency, celery

I have a celery setup with rabbitmq. The issue is that celery is moving tasks to reserved state while running a long task, and do not execute them until the long running task is completed.

I want to accomplish that without using routing, and enabling "-Ofair" flag does the job. [Prefork pool prefetch settings](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/optimizing.html#prefork-pool-prefetch-settings)

How to enable the flag in celery python? Thanks

I am using celery 3.1.19

```
$ celery report
software -> celery:3.1.19 (Cipater) kombu:3.0.32 py:3.4.3
            billiard:3.3.0.22 py-amqp:1.4.8
platform -> system:Linux arch:64bit, ELF imp:CPython
loader   -> celery.loaders.default.Loader
settings -> transport:amqp results:disabled
```

I am using Celery as follows and concurrency is set to 4:

```
app = celery.Celery()
app.conf.update(
    BROKER_URL=broker,
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=backend,
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER='json',
    CELERY_IMPORTS=imports or [],
    CELERYD_CONCURRENCY=concurrency,
    CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER=False
)
```

Here is how I start the worker:

```
worker = app.Worker(
    hostname=hostname,
    queues=[hostname]
)
worker.start()
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to set the flag in the celery settings?

Comment: yes using the configuration options or another solution for the issue

Comment: What is wrong with using -Ofair?

Comment: I can't use the "-Ofair" option because I am running the celery worker with python and not with the command line

Comment: Please show how you are starting the worker. You can set options there. In your question I only see your Celery configuration

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to run it this way.

```
worker = app.Worker(
    hostname=hostname,
    queues=[hostname],
    optimization='fair'
)
worker.start()
```

Comment: It works, Thanks. Where did you find it? I couldn't find that option anywhere in celery docs

Comment: What if I have the following setup?
```
app = Celery(..)
app.config_from_object('some_module:some_class')
```